# connect usb pickit3 before of after start mplab ipe v3.45

Tags: pic, usb

I'm having trouble making work pickit3 because when you start the software then plug the usb pickit 3 to laptop compiler doesnot recognice pickit3, anybony knows what this problema happen for?

Comment: It would help to know basic information such as what os you are using. IPE detects programmers automatically when you plug them in while it is running.

Answer (score 2):

Your question makes no sense since the compiler has nothing to do with a PicKit3.

MPLAB looks to see what devices there are at startup.  While plugging in a device after starting MPLAB may work, it is best to have the device connected to the computer before MPLAB is started.